# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ListenHTTP processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi cluster with a flow which starts with listenHTTP processor. Basically flow receives POST calls with JSON payload. It works fine with postman request or a curl call. But when a request comes from a web browser, the OPTION request fails with following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://{server_endpoint}/process' from 
origin 'https://{client_endpoint}:3443' has been blocked by CORS 
policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource 
with CORS disabled.
```

How should we configure cors in ListenHTTP processor.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListenHTTP` does not support CORS. Your only option is to use a proxy server that will be the one to send your browser requests to the NiFi cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can do it using the `HandleHttpRequest` / `HandleHttpResponse` processors.

In the `HandleHttpRequest`, you have to allow for the `OPTIONS` and `POST` verbs.

In the `HandleHttpResponse`, make sure to add the HTTP headers required for CORS (and that fit your needs). For instance:

[image]